# Create Class from Usage where name already exists in other package

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.3. I type in `public final Foo bar;` It says can't find Foo, but there is a Foo in a different package it can find. But I do not want to use that Foo, I want to create a new Foo. But I can't figure out how to do it. Just pressing Alt+Enter imports the existing foo instead of bringing up a list of possible actions. Is there some way to get it create the class from usage instead of assuming I want to import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little bit awkward but what you have to do is to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the time the popup ask if you want to import the current `Foo` class and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to bring up the new popup with alternatives to create a new class.

**First it asks if you want to import your existing `Foo` and this is where you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>**
[image]

**Then you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> so it is selectable that you want to create a new class**

[image]